# Vim code formating with astyle (formatprg in vimrc)

Tags: vim, formatting, astyle

I'm trying to use [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) as my code formatter in Vim. However, I can't seem to find how to tell vim which options to use for astyle.

The following is in my vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set formatprg=astyle\
```

If given no options in command line mode, astyle will try to find an options file [named .astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Option_Files). However this does not seem to work here. (Ie: when I format in vim: `gqG` the result is totaly different than if I had called astyle from the command line !)
This is my .astyle options file:

```
 --style=allman
 --mode=c
 --attach-classes              # -xc
 --attach-closing-while        # -xV
 --indent-classes              # -C
 --keep-one-line-blocks        # -O
 --keep-one-line-statements    # -o
 --align-pointer=name          # -k3
```

So I tried to simply specify the options in my vimrc like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363475):

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set formatprg=astyle\ --style=allman --mode=c -xc -xV -C -O -o -k3
```

Saved, sourced, reloaded vim entierly: no change. The options seem to not take effect. When I format with `gggqG` the result is still not what my options ask for... Can anyone see why this is not working ?

(Note: I want to be able to format using `gq` and I don't mind reformatting the whole file entierly each time, unlike in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587940/using-astyle-in-vim))

EDIT:
After a few stupid mistakes I've escaped all the spaces as suggested in @romainl comment. However there seems to be an error comming from vim which I cannot interpret:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

shell returned 1

E485: Can't read file /tmp/vHXZmnp/3
```

Comment: You need to escape all the spaces in the value of `&formatprg`: `astyle\ --style=allman\ --mode=c\ -xc\ ...`.

Comment: @romainl is it really that simple ? -_-

Comment: Only one way to know…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one is answering, I'll share what I managed to come up with.
Following the advice given in the comments I escaped all the spaces in the sequence of options passed to astyle. However, this leads to bash trying to interpret the options, failing and kindly telling us so: see question edit.

The solution that seems to work is to create a system wide astyle options file and pass the path to that using command line arguments instead of giving it the options directly.
(This can probably also be done with a project options file but requires having an options file at the root directory of every project)

Taking my options file `.astylerc` in my home directory this gives:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp set formatprg=astyle\ --options="/home/myusername/.astylerc"\
```

Note that a relative path did not work, but it is possible to write the path to the options file using a 'pseudo relative' path using the `$HOME` environment variable as mentioned in the [astyle documentation](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_Option_Files)