# Cleaning up tabs, spacing, etc on a Ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a series of scripts that have a mixture of all kinds of spacing, tabs, or a complete lack thereof.  Is there anything that can parse and clean .rb files in a similar manner to HTML Tidy?

Comment: This is a standard feature of Ruby IDEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [Ruby Script Beautifier](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html).

Answer (score 3):

1. Open in Vim
2. [`gg=G`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506075/how-do-i-fix-the-indentation-of-an-entire-file-in-vi)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of this.  Looks like it works for indentation, but doesn't help with spacing or excess line returns -- still a big step in the right direction though.

Comment: Sorry, yes the `=` is Vim's indentation command. I didn't realise from your question that you meant not-at-the-start-of-the-line spacings

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/libc/tidy_ffi

This is also a nice solution, and works with 1.9.