# Re-indenting multiple files (LaTex) with Vim

Tags: bash, vim, indentation, auto-indent

Background: I've decided to try Vim with latex-suite as my editor for a largish LaTeX project. As I've switched to Vim from different editor/IDE which didn't force autoindent (and I was sloppy with indenting manually), the current indentation of .tex files is quite mismatched and doesn't suit the style I want (which is set up by adding `filetype plugin indent on` and `automcd Filetype tex setlocal shiftwidth= etc` in my .vimrc; this works fine).

The project constitutes of multiple .tex files, structured like

```
main.tex
tex/
   chapter1.tex
   chapter2.tex
   ...
   chapter10.tex
```

[This stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506075/how-do-i-fix-the-indentation-of-an-entire-file-in-vi) tells to indent a single source code file opened in vim easily with =, as in

```
gg=G
```

which works perfectly. Now, the question.

Is there a neat Vim (and/or bash/other if Vim can't handle this neatly, but preferrably Vim) solution which would enable me to do similar 'reindent' for *all* the .tex files at once (in other words, without typing `gg=G` separately for each tex file where the indentation needs to be fixed?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add all LaTeX files as *arguments* in Vim (the example assumes you're in the document's root):

```
:args *.tex **/*.tex
```

Then, you can apply the command to all arguments via `:argdo` (and `:normal`, since this is a normal-mode command); you probably want to persist the changes in the same go, too:

```
:argdo execute 'normal gg=G' | update
```