# Return to last cursor in VIM after indenting

Tags: vim, indentation

I use `gg=G` to auto-format the whole file in VIM. After the whole file is indented, the cursor is returned to the begining of the file.

How can I do so that VIM returns the cursor to the last position? Say I called the command in the line 45, I want VIM to return me to this line after indenting the file.

Edit: if anyone is interested, I did add the following command to my .vimrc

```
" Autoformat document                                                                                                                     
nnoremap F gg=G''
```

So by using `Shit+f` I can now reformat the whole document and stay at the same cursor.

Comment: You could create a mapping to : 1) mark the current position 2) do gg=G 3) go back to marked position. I use to have such a thing but I cannot fund the corresponding config anymore :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by /u/nemo157, in an answer comment in [How do I fix the indentation of an entire file in Vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506075/how-do-i-fix-the-indentation-of-an-entire-file-in-vi), issueing `''` returns you to your last position. As per vim docs:

```
                            *''* *``*
''  ``      To the position before the latest jump, or where the
            last "m'" or "m`" command was given.  Not set when the
            |:keepjumps| command modifier was used.
            Also see |restore-position|.
```

So if you do `gg=G''` you're back where you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set a named mark (e.g. `ma`) and return to that position after the reindenting with `` `a ``.

Alternatively, [the anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) provides a `:KeepView` command that makes *any* (Ex) command (so you need to translate with `:normal!` here) keep the current view:

```
:KeepView normal! gg=G
```