# format the shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have some 1000 lines shell script with all the kepywords

if/else, while, HERE document

Can anyone tell the best way to format the script, so the script looks good.

I was trying VG= in vim but that displaces HERE document content as well.

Comment: Add an example, further explain what you are trying to do. With this limited amount of information, we can't help you.

Comment: use gg=G to indent the entire file

Comment: @DanieleO 's solution does the work

Comment: @syadav I'll write it as answer, could you accept it in order to close the question? Thanks

Comment: I am not the OP. ;)

Comment: As metioned gg=G is not a good way to format the shell script as it indent entire file includeing HERE document which should not be. I am looking more for an external tool/plugin/script which can do this

Answer (score 12):

check this https://github.com/mvdan/sh,   here is the sample command for indent with two spaces

`shfmt -i 2 -w yourscript`

Answer (score 1):

By default the `gg=G` gives you 8 tab spaces. To reduce the 8 tab spaces to 3 spaces edit your `.vimrc` file:

```
set tabstop=3
set shiftwidth=3
set expandtab
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506075/how-do-i-fix-the-indentation-of-an-entire-file-in-vi) qives you a good, in context discussion of everything `gg=G` related.

Comment: The problem with gg=G is it indent the HERE document code as well

Comment: Ex - cat << EOF

Answer (score 1):

I found a VSCode plugin based on https://github.com/mvdan/sh , support the .sh .bash Dockerfile .gitignore .properties /etc/hosts ...

Homepage:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=foxundermoon.shell-format

macOS usage:

`shift`+`option`+`f`

or

`shift`+`command`+`p` then type Format Document

Answer (score 0):

Using VIM add the parameter below in order to indent the entire file

```
gg=G
```

Comment: you must add the steps also , how to add this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm's BashSupport plugin now has an experimental `bash` code formatter.

[Sadly the BashSupport plugin "will only receive fixes for major problems" as of 2017](https://github.com/jansorg/BashSupport).