# Vim Autoindent not working with HTML/XML

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct indentation of HTML and PHP using Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459478/correct-indentation-of-html-and-php-using-vim)

My vim autoindent works splendidly for PHP, but it never seems to work for XML/HTML.  Here's my vimrc:

```
set autoindent
filetype indent on
set pastetoggle=<F2>
set number
set incsearch
set wildmode=longest,list
set hidden
set title
set scrolloff=3
set cindent
```