# How to edit HTML in Vim?

Tags: html, vim, indentation, ftplugin

I'm new to Vim and I'm trying to get used to it. I just created a .vimrc file and got Vim to display line numbers and do incremental searching. I also enabled syntax highlighting. Now I want to enable things to make writing HTML easier. I searched for html.vim in /usr/share/vim and found this:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/html.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/html.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim72/indent/html.vim
```

Now, what do I have to do to enable HTML auto indentation? Copy those files to ~/.vim? Symlink them? Or does Vim automagically load them from /usr/share/vim/? (It already does HTML syntax highlighting, so I think that's possible - but it doesn't do HTML auto indenting)
I heard `set autoindent` in .vimrc would do the trick, but what's with .c files? I thought they needed `set cindent`, but does cindent work with HTML?

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459478/correct-indentation-of-html-and-php-using-vim/462547#462547

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The very first thing you should do is try `vimtutor` and complete it a couple of times. Once the basics are covered you can start to play with plugins…

[SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) is inspired by TextMate's snippets and/so is beautiful, it has a lot of HTML snippets by default and it's extremely easy to add your own. To use it, type `div` then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to obtain:

```
<div id="|">

</div>
```

with the caret between the `""` ready for you to type an id; hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to move the caret on the blank line:

```
<div id="myId">
    |
</div>
```

Beautiful. Many editors have this feature, though.

If you have a lot of HTML to write — say a few emails/newsletters a day — another plugin called [SparkUp](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) allows you to produce complex HTML with only a few key strokes and some CSS knowledge. You start by typing something like:

```
table[id=myTable] > tr*3 > td*2 > img
```

then you hit `<C-e>` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) to obtain:

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="|" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

with the caret inside the first empty `""`. Hit `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` to go to the next/previous field.

Magical. The plugin is available for more editors, though.

I second text objects and Surround.vim which are unbelievably useful.

Another cool feature is the visual-block mode (`:help visual-block`) where you can select columns of text. Say you have:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
    <li><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
    <li><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
    <li><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
</ul>
```

place your cursor on the `>` of the first `<li>`then hit `<C-v>`and move the cursor downward to the fourth `<li>`. Hit `I` (capital I) to enter INSERT mode just before the `>` and type `class="myElement"` then `<Esc>` to obtain:

```
<ul>
    <li class="myElement"><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
    <li class="myElement"><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
    <li class="myElement"><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
    <li class="myElement"><p>My text doesn't mean anything</p></li>
</ul>
```

Ho yeah!

Seriously, Vim is great.

Comment: +1 For mentioning Sparkup.  I've been meaning to try that for a while now.

Comment: @Michael — Thanks. I reserve SparkUp for very specific tasks where I am forced to use huge nested tables like newsletters and such. Where you have a rigid and predictable structure. When I'm working in a more freeform manner I find SnipMate more convenient. But I'm a recovering TextMate user, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at [the AutoCloseTag plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2591) to close tags as you type them.  And `set autoindent` should be handling HTML indentation for you.

Also you should read the docs in `:help text-objects` to learn about using the inner and outer tag selections.  For example, in normal mode you can do <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to change the text inside the current tag.  Or in visual mode <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> will expand the visual selection to encapsulate the tag around the cursor.

Finally, [look at the Surround.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697), which can surround a selection or text object with a tag, or change the tag around it.

Comment: `set autoindent`? But what's with C? Will that filetype plugin handle these cases for me?