# vim auto indentation not working

Tags: vim

I can't get autoindentation to work for me in Vim. Anytime I press `return`, my cursor always goes to the first column on the next line and I have to manually indent the correct amount of space before typing. Is there any way to fix this? None of the existing answers I found SO have helped. I'm editing a Laravel view file called `login.blade.php`.

Here is the contents of my `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set cindent
colorscheme itg_flat
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

It appears this is only an issue in `.blade.php` files. I think the problem is that it's a .php file but contains HTML code. So the HTML code is not being intended properly since the files extensions is php. If I write HTML code in a .html file, it works correctly.

Comment: Are you inadvertently in "paste" mode? That would reset your indenting config. Try: `:se paste?`

Comment: Not in paste mode. Please see my update.

Comment: You may find something useful in this post, in that case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459478/correct-indentation-of-html-and-php-using-vim

Comment: Probably try to update the indent script with this vim plugin : http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=604

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably a little late to help the author of this question but for anyone else who is struggling with this issue I was able to fix it by changing the filetype and syntax of the blade.php files to html. Autoindentation then worked as expected.

You can do this by adding a couple of lines in your vimrc as follows:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.blade.php set syntax=html
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.blade.php set filetype=html
```

Comment: Vim's own filetype plugin for PHP turns off `autoindent`, `cindent` and `smartindent`. Thankfully, Vim provide's a standard way to override settings set by filetype plugins, either before or after the plugins are loaded. Consult `:help ftplugin-overrule` for a better way to re-enable `autoindent` for PHP files.