# Vim : Extra tab after begin new line

Tags: vim

I'm doing a "autocmd BufNewFile" for my php class file in my .vimrc.
I need to implement standard method, and I want to write them in one line. Here is my probleme, when I press 'o' to begin a newline after a oneline function, I get an "extra tab" who ruins my identation.

```
    // "one line" example
    Class Example {                                    // 0 tab
        function foo() {return ('foo');}               //1 tab
            function fuu(){}                           //2 tab, I want 1 ofc.
    }

    // discusting example without bug
    Class Example {                                   // 0 tab
        function foo() {return ('foo');               // 1 tab
        }                                             // 1 tab
        function fuu(){}                              // 1 tab
    }
```

Does anyone got an idea to make this work as exepected?

Here is the interesting part of my .vimrc

```
    set tabstop=4
    set softtabstop=0 noexpandtab
    set shiftwidth=4
    set term=xterm-256color
    syntax on
    set nowrap
    set mouse=a
    set ruler
    set colorcolumn=80
    set showmatch
    set list
    " Showing tab
    set listchars=tab:>-,trail:-
    highlight SpecialKey guifg=grey ctermfg=darkgrey


    set nocompatible
    set number

    "Better command completion
    set wildmenu
    set wildmode=list:longest
```

Comment: Have you enabled autoindent? Try enabling it with `:se ai` and see if it improves things.

Comment: Sorry I just notice that my problem is more.. mystic.
I thought that was a strange "stable" bug, but no, it just ident randomly one or two tab after the one line function... maybe a weird plugin or something, i'll find some fix by myself.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue looks related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4085045/4013519).

If `set ft=html` or `set ft=phtml` doesn't solve your problem, you should consider trying out one of those plugins: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=604 or https://github.com/2072/PHP-Indenting-for-VIm